# Edit text file after string PHP

Tags: php, html, text

I need to add text (let's say the word "Hello"), along with a newline, after a string ("Comments:") in a text file, while also keeping the text that comes afterwards. How can I go about adding this text?

#### Edit:

My text file looks like this:

```
Comments:
<new comment goes here>
<older comments here>
```

I want to put my new text in place of "`<new comment goes here>`", while also keeping "`<older comments here>`"

Comment: *"after "Comments:""* - What comments? If you want to add something, concatenate and a new line is `"\n"` - Show full code.

Answer (score 1):

Use **file_put_contents**

```
<?php
    $file = 'comm.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    $current .= "Write something here\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes. I was looking for something similar to this, but I need the text to be displayed after "Comments:" at the top of the file, but before the rest of the older comments.

Comment: There must be a way to cut the contents at a certain point. I just need to squeeze the new text between `Comments:` and all the older comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for the same.

> int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [, int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )

for eg:

```
$text = explode("\n", file_get_contents('comm.txt'), 2);  
file_put_contents('comm.txt', $text[0]."\nHello\n".$text[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = 'comm.txt';
$wholecontent = file_get_contents($file);
$commenttoreplace= current(explode("\n", $wholecontent)); 
$newcomment=$commenttoreplace."comment what yo like to add";
file_put_contents($file, str_replace($commenttoreplace,$newcomment,$wholecontent));
?>
```

above ex will work,please tell if any issue